# Batch file - Make Variable Menu

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a menu here that you can navigate using keys using the choice command. The problem is that I want this menu to have a variable number of options. At the moment, if there are more than 3 drives detected, it will list only 3 of them. If there are less, it will list some options of N/A. Is there an easy way (without set /p) to make this exact menu with the same navigation method, but with variable options? Here's the link to the code I'm talking about

```
:list1
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Drives:
echo -------------------
echo ^> Drive !1a!
echo.
echo   Drive !2a!
echo.
echo   Drive !3a!
echo.
echo Other options:
echo -------------------
echo   Exit
echo.
echo   Back
echo.
echo Use WSX to navigate this menu.
endlocal
choice /c WSX /n >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" goto list5
if "%errorlevel%" == "2" goto list2
if "%errorlevel%" == "3" goto list1a
goto list

:list2
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Drives:
echo -------------------
echo   Drive !1a!
echo.
echo ^> Drive !2a!
echo.
echo   Drive !3a!
echo.
echo Other options:
echo -------------------
echo   Exit
echo.
echo   Back
echo.
echo Use WSX to navigate this menu.
endlocal
choice /c WSX /n >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" goto list1
if "%errorlevel%" == "2" goto list3
if "%errorlevel%" == "3" goto list2a
goto list2

:list3
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Drives:
echo -------------------
echo   Drive !1a!
echo.
echo   Drive !2a!
echo.
echo ^> Drive !3a!
echo.
echo Other options:
echo -------------------
echo   Exit
echo.
echo   Back
echo.
echo Use WSX to navigate this menu.
endlocal
choice /c WSX /n >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" goto list2
if "%errorlevel%" == "2" goto list4
if "%errorlevel%" == "3" goto list3a
endlocal
goto list3

:list4
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Drives:
echo -------------------
echo   Drive !1a!
echo.
echo   Drive !2a!
echo.
echo   Drive !3a!
echo.
echo Other options:
echo -------------------
echo ^> Exit
echo.
echo   Back
echo.
echo Use WSX to navigate this menu.
endlocal
choice /c WSX /n >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" goto list3
if "%errorlevel%" == "2" goto list5
if "%errorlevel%" == "3" goto end
goto list4

:list5
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Drives:
echo -------------------
echo   Drive !1a!
echo.
echo   Drive !2a!
echo.
echo   Drive !3a!
echo.
echo Other options:
echo -------------------
echo   Exit
echo.
echo ^> Back
echo.
echo Use WSX to navigate this menu.
endlocal
choice /c WSX /n >nul
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" goto list4
if "%errorlevel%" == "2" goto list1
if "%errorlevel%" == "3" goto menu1
goto list4
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the W, S & X options mean. If I see a menu showing three Drives an Exit and a Back, how do I know which item matches which choice letter option?

Comment: Where and how are defined `1a`, `2a` and `3a`?

Comment: W goes up, S goes down, and X selects the option. This is just part of the file, the part that is relevant

Comment: You don't press any of the buttons to specifically select one of them. You use W and S to move a pointer next to different options, and X to select the option shown next to the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old but I thought that maybe I could still help other people if they are wondering how they can make menus like you wanted to in batch.

I have modified your code so it is much smaller but it won't work right out of the box because you have left quite a few variables unknown for us in your post. Although, if you chucked this into the same script you had, it should work perfectly fine.

Instead of using multiple labels with the menu written out all the time, you can use one label with a for loop to loop through all of the drives. You will need to count the amount of drives that you have in some other area of the code (not related to what you asked so I didn't include it) and store it as the variable `%drives_total%`.

When you press `W`, it will check if it is at the top of the list (value being `1`) and if it isn't then it will decrease the value of `%menu_pos%`. The same happens for pressing `S`, but instead it checks if it is at the bottom of the list (value being `%drives_total%`), and if it isn't it will increase the value of `%menu_pos%`.

When it comes to pressing `X`, it will check if it is the exit or back buttons, if it is, go to their respective label, else it will go to the label `list%menu_pos%a`. If you were on the first drive, it would go to `list1a`, if it was on the second drive, it would go to `list2a`, etc.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set menu_pos=1
set /a max_menu_pos=%drives_total% + 2
set /a exit_button_pos=%drives_total% + 1
set /a back_button_pos=%drives_total% + 2

:list
cls
echo Drives:
echo -------------------
for /l %%a in (1,1,%drives_total%) do (
    if %%a==%menu_pos% (
        echo ^> Drive !%%aa!
    ) else (
        echo   Drive !%%aa!
    )
    echo.
)
echo Other options:
echo -------------------
if %menu_pos%==%exit_button_pos% (
    echo ^> Exit
) else echo   Exit
echo.
if %menu_pos%==%back_button_pos% (
    echo ^> Back
) else echo   Back
echo.
echo Use WSX to navigate this menu.
choice /c WSX /n >nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
    if %menu_pos% NEQ 1 set /a menu_pos-=1
) else if "%errorlevel%"=="2" (
    if %menu_pos% NEQ %max_menu_pos% set /a menu_pos+=1
) else if "%errorlevel%"=="3" (
    if %menu_pos%==%exit_button_pos% (
        goto end
    ) else if %menu_pos%==%back_button_pos% (
        goto menu1
    ) else (
        goto list%menu_pos%a
    )
)
goto list
```

I hope this helps.