# List all mp4 files with for loop and select one with choice

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was able to list mp4 files in a directory with a for loop, and depending on how many files are listed, a parameter is passed to the choice command. What I wasn't able to do is to select a file from a list that has been created with a for loop? This way I hope to use the selected file in another command as a parameter.

Here my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 0
echo.
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  set /a count += 1
  echo [!count!] %%f
)
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
  call set "cOpt=%%cOpt%%%%a"
)
echo.
choice /C %cOpt% /M "Select input video:"
echo %errorlevel% # selected option is shown here but no filename
endlocal
```

Comment: [you may find this relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990813/batch-file-make-variable-menu/61823099#61823099)

Comment: The easiest way was to do the same `for %%f` loop again but instead of echoing, check whether `!count!` equals `!ErrorLevel!`, then you have the chosen file. Alternatively, you could store the file names in (pseudo-)array variables (like `set "name[!count!]=%%f"`) and then access it by `for %%I in (!ErrorLevel!) do echo !name[%%I]!`. By the way, why do you use `call set "cOpt=%%cOpt%%%%a"` when `set "cOpt=!cOpt!%%a"` would be simpler? Also you could build the list of choices already in the first loop…

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions

:Menu
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('(Set File[^) 2^> NUL') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=[]" %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %__AppDir__%where.exe ".":"*.mp4" 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe /N /V ""') Do Set "File[%%G]=%%~nxH" & Echo %%G. %%~nxH
If Not Defined File[1] GoTo :EOF

:Select
Set "#="
Set /P "#=Choose a file from the list by entering its item number. "
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('(Set File[%#%]^) 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe "="') Do Set "File[#]=%%H"
If Not Defined File[#] GoTo Select

:Main
Echo You chose item number %#% which was assigned to "%File[#]%" & Pause
```

You would obviously modify the last line to be your required command with parameter.

*If you wish to include the full paths, simply change both instances of `%%~nxH` on line `5`, to `%%H`. Additionally if you wish to stipulate a location, instead of the current directory, change `"."`, on the same line to e.g. `"Y:\our\Path"`.*